# trying to draw over a timage

Tags: delphi, timage

I have written a simple program (using Delphi XE7); it has a TImage and a TPaintBox (partially over the Timage). In the FormPaint procedure I am calling "BringToFront" and then drawing a (filled) rectangle. The rectangle appears *under* the image.

```
procedure TForm1.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
begin
 with paintbox1 do
   begin
     BringToFront;
     canvas.Rectangle(0,0,width-1,height-1);
   end;
end;
```

This is a image of the program window:

[image]

I expected the rectangle to be *over* the image.
What am I doing wrong? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using PaintBox correctly. PaintBox has its own event for drawing. You should use `TPaintBox.OnPaint` instead of `TForm.OnPaint` and result will be as you wrote.

<s>You can also draw directly on the picture. In this case, used event `TForm.OnPaint`</s>.

You can also draw directly on the image after its picture has changed (for example, after loading). It works if used TBitmap graphics.

```
procedure TForm1.button1click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  image1.LoadFromFile('c:\temp\1.bmp')
  image1.canvas.Rectangle(0,0,100,100);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks very much! Silly mistake. :)

Comment: The `TForm.OnPaint` event is the wrong place to draw on a `TImage`, too. `TImage` holds a `TPicture` and handles its own drawing events to render that picture.

Comment: I agree that it is wrong to use `TForm.OnPaint`. But `TImage` and `TPicture` has no events for drawing. I correct answer.